# last reboot in local time zone?

Tags: last, uptime

Is there a way to tell this command to output the data in local time (not UTC)?

```
last reboot
```

Version:

```
last --version
last von util-linux 2.27.1
```

Comment: Does `last reboot` not honour the `TZ` environment variable?  I don't have any machines that have rebooted since the start of `wtmp`, but certainly logins and the `wtmp` start date are printed according to `TZ` ("last from util-linux 2.28.1").  E.g. `TZ=UTC last reboot` or `TZ=Australia/Perth last reboot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TZ` if you need some (troublesome on account of the horrible daylight savings time swings) local timezone, as @Toby indicates:

```
% TZ=US/Pacific last | sed -n /reboot/p | sed -n 1p
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-642.1.1.e Mon Jul 25 09:55 - 08:47 (29+22:51)  
% last | sed -n /reboot/p | sed -n 1p 
reboot   system boot  2.6.32-642.1.1.e Mon Jul 25 16:55 - 15:47 (29+22:51)  
%
```

Comment: There is a next question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/305625/set-tz-according-to-etc-localtime (How to set TZ according to /etc/localtime?)